# How to get the request data body through ServerWebExchange?

Tags: spring-webflux

The data body in the request can be obtained through ServerWebExchange, but this data structure can not be converted into a string, although I can get a string method.

```
Flux<DataBuffer> requestBody = exchange.getRequest().getBody();
```

Answer (score 1):

exchange.getAttribute("cachedRequestBodyObject")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).